# Cakephp 4.x Custom Query

Tags: sql, cakephp

Can someone help how can i generate this query to Cakephp Query Builder.
I am upgrading my 2.x project to 4.x,

```
SELECT
  Saving.id,
  SUM(IFNULL(Saving.interest,0)) + SUM(IFNULL(CASE SavingSub.type when '1' AND SavingSub.interest <= 0 then SavingSub.amount else 0 end,0)) + SUM(IFNULL(CASE SavingSub.type when '1' AND SavingSub.interest > 0 then SavingSub.interest else 0 end,0)) - SUM(IFNULL(CASE SavingSub.type when '0' then SavingSub.amount else 0 end,0)) - SUM(IFNULL(Saving.interest,0)) as total 

FROM 
 savings as Saving 
 left join saving_subs as SavingSub On SavingSub.saving_id = Saving.id 
where 
  Saving.visible = true and 
  SavingSub.visible = true
group by
  Saving.id
```

Comment: Note your `left join` is effectively `inner` due to `where ...SavingSub.visible =` 
 Are you sure?

Comment: What specifically do you have a problem with? Functions? Case expressions? Joins? etc...

Comment: Exactly, do you have prepared models and relations or not yet?

Comment: The problem here is Cakephp 4.x remove the custom query pagination feature.
My Cakephp 2.x is using that feature . Now i am converting that SQL Query to Query Builder since Cakephp 4.x has no more Custom Query Pagination . 

To be specific . I am working in my index pagination with that query . 
But i cant see any reference how to apply that query into Query builder or any cakephp retrieving code for pagination.

Sorry for my english

Comment: $this->hasMany('SavingSubs', [
            'foreignKey' => 'saving_id',
        ]);

this my relationship with saving_subs table

Answer (score 1):

How I did it (not sure if this is the best solution of if it works in your case):

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
...
class SomeTable extends Table
{
    public function someFunction() {
        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
        $statement = $connection->execute(
            'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.id = :id',
            ['id' => $id]
        )->fetchAll('assoc');           
        
        return $statement;      
    }
}
```

If you don't have variables in your query you can just leave the :id and array ['id' => $id] away.

Comment: Can i paginate the result ?